# frequency of elements in array in $\mathcal{O}(n) ? $

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I have an array of 64-bit integers of length $n$ and I want to find the frequency of each element in $\mathcal{O}(n)$? is that possible?

my idea was to use a hashmap but it seems to me that the adversary would always be able to find a pathological case.

Comment: Yes, you can use HashMap. `adversary would always be able to find a pathological case`: you can use your own hash function: $h(x) = p \cdot x \pmod {m}$, where $p$ and $m$ are (large) prime numbers randomly selected at the beginning of the program. While adversarial inputs exist (e.g. $0$, $m$, $2m$, ...), the adversary doesn't know them, since they don't know $p$ and $m$.

Comment: Since they are integers of fixed length, you can sort them in $O(n)$ and then count their repetitions in one pass.

Comment: Use radix sort with an "alphabet" of size 256, say.

Comment: Is there a limit on the $n$?

Comment: Since the integers are all upper bounded by an absolute constant the "counting" part of counting sort already solves the problem in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Isn't counting sort O(n+k)=O(n+2^64)?

Comment: Yes, it is, which still gives $\mathcal O(n)$, right?